# Printing all values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code that prints out the first value in the array (Twitter post):

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($twitter_customer_key, $twitter_customer_secret, $twitter_access_token, $twitter_access_token_secret);

$my_tweets = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => 'xxx', 'count' => 10));

echo '<div class="tweets">';
if(isset($my_tweets->errors))
{           
echo 'Error :'. $my_tweets->errors[0]->code. ' - '. $my_tweets->errors[0]->message;
}else{
echo makeClickableLinks($my_tweets[0]    ->text);
}
echo '</div>';
```

However, I want to print out all values in the array. I have tried using below method as stated here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

```
array_values($my_tweets)
```

But that returns the following:  "Trying to get property of non-object"

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    for($i = 0; $i<=count($my_tweets) -1; $i++){
        if(isset($my_tweets[$i]->errors)){                   
            echo 'Error :'. $my_tweets->errors[$i]->code. ' - '. $my_tweets->errors[$i]->message;
        } else{
            echo makeClickableLinks($my_tweets[$i]->text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I get the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line 59

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump($my_tweets);
```

OR

```
print_r($my_tweets);
```

You can also loop

```
foreach($my_tweets as $tweet){
    echo $tweet;
}
```